# Bootstrap 5 dim background on navbar toggle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use Bootstrap 5 navbar on my webpage. Is there a simple way to dim the background (page) when the hamburger menu is clicked (expanded)? And remove the dim when the hamburger menu is collapsed. Just like the page dim on modal fade.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an JSfiddle or codepen example to your post next time so it's easier to test out a solution.

Right now I came up with this simple JQuery solution but I am not sure if it will work with your code because I haven't tested it out. In theory it should work.

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar > button').on('click', function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('color-changed');
    });
    });
```

CSS

```
.color-changed{
background-color:grey!important;
}
```

Solution 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar > button').on('click', function(){
        $('div, body, html').not('.navbar').toggleClass('color-changed');
    });
    });
```

CSS

```
.color-changed{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Solution 3

Add this HTML code to somewhere in your .html file

```
<div class="color-changed">
```

Add this CSS

```
.color-changed{
  display:none;
width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar button').on('click', function(){
        $('.color-changed').toggle();
    });
    });
```

Comment: The JQuery worked, and the CSS changed the background color to gray. But, I want the entite page to dim, except the navbar. Just like the page dim when a modal is opened.

Comment: I added 2 extra possible solutions. See if these work for you.